# Apply a different conv1d filter to each input channel

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a Tensorflow model in which a separate 1d convolution should be applied to each of N input channels. I've played around with the various convXd functions. So far I've got something working where each filter is applied to each channel, resulting in N x N outputs, from which I can select a diagonal. But this seems quite inefficient. Any ideas on how to only convolve filter i with input channel i? Thanks for any suggestions!

Code illustrating my best working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(tf.__version__)

# [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
X_size = [5, 109, 2, 1]

# [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
W_size = [10, 1, 1, 2]

mX = np.zeros(X_size)
mX[0,10,0,0]=1
mX[0,40,1,0]=2

mW = np.zeros(W_size)
mW[1:3,0,0,0]=1
mW[3:6,0,0,1]=-1

X = tf.Variable(mX, dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(mW, dtype=tf.float32)

# convolve everything
Y = tf.nn.conv2d(X, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

# now only preserve the outputs for filter i + input i
Y_desired = tf.matrix_diag_part(Y)    

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(Y.shape)
    Yout = sess.run(fetches=Y)

# Yes=desired output, No=extraneous output
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(Yout[0,:,0,0])
plt.title('Yes: W filter 0 * X channel 0')
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(Yout[0,:,1,0])
plt.title('No: W filter 0 * X channel 1')
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(Yout[0,:,0,1])
plt.title('No: W filter 1 * X channel 0')
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(Yout[0,:,1,1])
plt.title('Yes: W filter 1 * X channel 1')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here's a revised version incorporating the suggestion to use depthwise_conv2d:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(tf.__version__)

# [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
X_size = [5, 1, 109, 2]

# [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
W_size = [1, 10, 2, 1]

mX = np.zeros(X_size)
mX[0,0,10,0]=1
mX[0,0,40,1]=2

mW = np.zeros(W_size)
mW[0,1:3,0,0]=1
mW[0,3:6,1,0]=-1

X = tf.Variable(mX, dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(mW, dtype=tf.float32)

Y = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(X, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    Yout = sess.run(fetches=Y)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(Yout[0,0,:,0])
plt.title('Yes: W filter 0 * X channel 0')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(Yout[0,0,:,1])
plt.title('Yes: W filter 1 * X channel 1')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for [depthwise convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d). This builds separate filters for each input channel. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a 1D version built-in, however most 1D convolution implementations just use 2D under the hood anyway. You can do something like this:

```
inp = ...  # assume this is your input, shape batch x time (or width or whatever) x channels
inp_fake2d = inp[:, tf.newaxis, :, :]  # add a fake second spatial dimension
filters = tf.random_normal([1, w, channels, 1])
out_fake2d = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(inp_fake2d, filters, [1,1,1,1], "valid")
out = out_fake2d[:, 0, :, :]
```

This adds a "fake" second spatial dimension of size 1, then convolves a filter (that is also size 1 in the fake dimension, no nothing is convolved in that direction) and finally removes the fake dimension again. Note that the fourth dimension in the filter tensor (which is also size 1) is the number of filters per input channel. Since you want just one separate filter for each channel, this number is 1.

I hope I understood the question correctly, because I'm a bit confused by the fact that your input `X` is 4D to begin with (usually you would use 1D convolution for 3D inputs). However you might be able to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, thanks! (And sorry about the confusion. I expanded my example out to a 2d convolution because I hadn't been able to get the 1d version to do what I needed, even ineffeciently.) Version of my code that incorporates your suggestions is above.

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer is satisfactory, consider upvoting and accepting it so that future visitors can see it more easily.

Comment: Admins ! this answer should be accepted for sure.